# Android set elements of listview cell WITHOUT custom listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, view, element, custom-adapter

I want to do something like `mylistview.setElementsofView(0).getElementById.setColor("black");`

currently the only way I know of doing this is setting up a custom list view adapter, setting up constructors, do conditional checks to see if view is populated, then do stuff in that view

this seems very convoluted, when other parts of the listview are so easily accessible.

is there some inherited function I can access in listview to allow me to access the elements of a particular view without a custom adapter?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question:

```
is there some inherited function I can access in listview to allow me to access the elements of a particular view without a custom adapter?
```

unfortunately is no.

Why do you think setting up a custom adapter is so convoluted?   Just make the  customized adapter class a nested class within your activity.  Most likely, you'd only be looking at overriding the getView() method.   In the end, you'll spend a lot less time doing this than looking for a "simple" solution.

Comment: very true, there is a feature I want to implement but it isn't very important and would require a custom adapter (unless it didn't)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
myListView.getChild(index).setColor("black");
```